# How can I call my voicemail in Bluebox Freeswitch?

Tags: voip, freeswitch

I'm using Bluebox to manage Freeswitch.  How can I call my voicemail?  If I dial my extension it takes my to the part where I need to record a voicemail.

If I dial 4000, *89 or 879 its just doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like an incomplete question, you could edit and update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question when I where looking for some answers of my own, and decided to answer your question.

In Bluebox you need to creative a number and then link it to your voicemail box.
You start by adding a new feature code in "Applications" -> "Feature Codes" and click on "Add Feature Code". Then you choose "Check Voicemail" in Feature.
Then under "Number assignment" you click on "Add Assignment" and then on "Add Number". In the pop-up box you fill in the number you want to link to Voicemail. For security you can choose to make the voicemail only accessed internally. After you have saved your new number you can save your newly created feature code and your access to the voicemail system.

I hope this helps..

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

To call your voicemail in Bluebox Freeswitch, you can use the following code:

```
<action application="voicemail" data="default ${caller_id_number}@default"/>
```

You can add this code to a display in your Bluebox Freeswitch configuration. When you dial your extension and it takes you to the voicemail recording, you can then dial this code to access your voicemail directly.

Alternatively, you can create an IVR menu with an option to access voicemail and use this code as the action for that option.

Note that the exact syntax of the dial plan code may depend on your specific configuration, so you may need to modify it slightly to work with your setup.